# all primary key values are used and there is no space for new rows. what can I do?

Tags: oracle, integer, primary-key, unique-index

I have an entity supper class that I can't change it and it contains an integer filed as OID(primary key). 
as you know integer can have values between  -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 and all these range is used now. unfortunately I can't change integer type to long. so hibernate start to create another valid key between this range but oracle says that's a unique constraint violation. 
any idea will be appreciated.
The entity class:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class EtVersionlessEntity
{
  private Integer oid;

  @Id
  public Integer getOid()
  {
    return this.oid;
  }
```

The Oracle column type is NUMBER(10).

Comment: I'd be curious to know what dataset you have that has 4 billion records in it...

Comment: it's technical values for insurance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

someone gave me a solution that I'd like to share as answer:

1. create a class similar as the class that is in jar file (with same
   name and package)
2. remove the "extends" and define a variable same
   name as the parent of type long:

   ```
   private long oid; 
   @Id
   public long getOid()
   {
      return this.oid;
   }
   ```

   3.go to ORM file and add all specifications for key like that is defined for parent

   ```
   <mapped-superclass class="EtEntity">
         <attributes>
            <id name="oid">
               <generated-value generator="HI_LO_SEQ" strategy="TABLE" />
               <table-generator name="HI_LO_SEQ" allocation-size="1000"/>
            </id>
        </attributes>
   </mapped-superclass>
   ```
3. change DB column to accept long values (NUMBER(19))

and that's it! worked...

Comment: "unfortunately I can't change integer type to long." ... so this is not really a solution, is it?

Comment: this is a solution. I could not change the jar file but this way is something like class overriding that I didn't know.

Answer (score 1):

Change the data-type to something that can hold bigger values.

> unfortunately I can't change integer type to long.

Then you are stuck; you need to use a larger data-type but you are unwilling/unable to do so so you have now run out of space.

You either:

- Accept that the data-types are not going to change and that you have run out of unique values; or
- You increase the size of the data-type you are using to allow you to have a bigger range of values.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any idea about changing database due to my accessibility to change DB. some kind of partitioning or ...